# Analog control Raspberry pi using pyPS4Controller

Tags: raspberry-pi, playstation

I have a Raspberry Pi with a robotic kit and I would like to control it using a PS4 controller but using analog input. I have successfully connected the controller and I can read events and program the motors to answer binary input. The [documentation (pyPS4Controller)](https://github.com/ArturSpirin/pyPS4Controller), however, is not explicit about using **analog** values (Ex: 50% press on R2 outputs 0.5 forward).

Could someone please help me figure out how to make this?
Thanks in advance!

```
# This is the example for binary buttons

from pyPS4Controller.controller import Controller

class MyController(Controller):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Controller.__init__(self, **kwargs)

    def on_x_press(self):
       print("Forward")

    def on_x_release(self):
       print("Stop")

# --> The objective is having some way to capture the "intensity" of the button press to use the motors accordingly

controller = MyController(interface="/dev/input/js0", connecting_using_ds4drv=False)
controller.listen()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tweaking and trial and error I ended up finding a solution.
The analog functions receive an input called `value` containing the analog value of the input given to the controller.

```
from pyPS4Controller.controller import Controller
from gpiozero import CamJamKitRobot as camjam

# Translate controller input into motor output values
def transf(raw):
    temp = (raw+32767)/65534
    # Filter values that are too weak for the motors to move
    if abs(temp) < 0.25:
        return 0
    # Return a value between 0.3 and 1.0
    else:
        return round(temp, 1)

class MyController(Controller):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Controller.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.robot = camjam()
    
    def on_R2_press(self, value):
        # 'value' becomes 0 or a float between 0.3 and 1.0
        value = transf(value)
        self.robot.value = (value, value)
        print(f"R2 {value}")
    
    def on_R2_release(self):
        self.robot.value = (0,0)
        print(f"R2 FREE")
    
    def on_L2_press(self, value):
        # 'value' becomes 0 or a float between -1.0 and -0.3
        value = -transf(value)
        self.robot.value = (value, value)
        print(f"L2 {value}")
    
    def on_L2_release(self):
        self.robot.value = (0,0)
        print(f"L2 FREE")
    
    # Press OPTIONS (=START) to stop and exit
    def on_options_press(self):
        print("\nExiting (START)")
        self.robot.value = (0,0)
        exit(1)


controller = MyController(interface="/dev/input/js0", connecting_using_ds4drv=False)
controller.listen()
```